# flatMap in Generator from online scala course by Martin Odersky

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Currently I am studying the online course "Principles of Reactive Programming"
by Martin Odersky, Erik Meijer, Roland Kuhn which is already ended a year ago, I guess there is nobody active in the discussion forum of this course so I put my question here for help, thanks very much.

In the session "Functional Random Generators" Martin gives an implementation of generator with flatMap methods, it is like:

```
trait Generator[+T] {
  self => // an alias for "this"

  def generate: T

  def map[S](f: T => S): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
      def generate = f(self.generate)
  }

  def flatMap[S](f: T => Generator[S]): Generator[S] = new Generator[S] {
      def generate = f(self.generate).generate
  }
}
```

I am not quite clear about the flatMap here, it returns a new Generator[S] with the defined generate method, but whose implementation depends on the "other" generate method from the "other" Generator[S] from input function argument f.

Here are my questions:

1) Are the Generator[S] by input function f and the Generator[S] returned by this flatMap method are of the same type?

2) If they are the same, how is generate method interpreted by compiler since it is defined by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the answer

1) the Generator[S] from input function f and the Generator[S] returned by flatMap method are of the same “abstract” type, but their instances could have different subtypes and therefore the “virtual” generate methods are different.

2) The generate method by the returned Generator[S] by input function f must have already defined in flatMap context. They are different generate methods from different real types.